# Ruby on Rails Javascript different in development/production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker

I have a problem with the gem 'jquery-datepicker'. My code in the application.js looks like this:

```
    //= require highcharts/highcharts.js
    //= require highcharts/highcharts-more.js
    //= require highcharts/highstock.js
    //= require highcharts/modules/exporting.js
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery.ui.datepicker
    //= require_tree .
    //= require_self
    $(function() {
      $( ".datepicker_von" ).datepicker({·
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        minDate: (new Date(2014,2,5)),  
        maxDate: 0,
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,·
        selectOtherMonths: true,
      });                      
      $( ".datepicker_bis" ).datepicker({·
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        minDate: (new Date(2014,2,5)),  
        maxDate: 0,            
        showAnim: "slideDown", 
        changeMonth: true,     
        changeYear: true,      
        showOtherMonths: true,·
        selectOtherMonths: true,
      });                      
    })
```

In the development environment the datepicker also appears, but in the production environment not. Now, when I change the application.js the // = require_self to the beginning:

```
    //= require_self
    //= require highcharts/highcharts.js
    //= require highcharts/highcharts-more.js
    //= require highcharts/highstock.js
    //= require highcharts/modules/exporting.js
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require jquery.ui.datepicker
    //= require_tree .
```

It works in the production environment but not in the development environment. I despair and need help.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

First of all do move (`jquery` and `jqery_ujs`)  to the top of manifest file

and add `document ready` for js datetimepicker

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".datepicker_von" ).datepicker({·
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        minDate: (new Date(2014,2,5)),  
        maxDate: 0,
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,·
        selectOtherMonths: true,
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can u tell me why i needed to change this? Because there is annother similar problem. As you can see above I use a highchart gem. It also works fine, but the export function (//= require hightcharts/modules/exporting) also only works in development environment. What do i need to change there?

Comment: `jquery` is base lib for many js libraries. Thus it's good to place on the top of the file. Also remove `.js` extension from require. If you have problems with hightchar try to better use the gem (also it has a good documantaion with require examples) https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails